# Kotlin plugin 1.3.70 update is failing to install

Tags: android, android-studio, kotlin, plugins, failed-installation

On Android Studio's suggestion, I am trying to install the Kotlin `1.3.70-realease-Studio3.6-1` , after Downloading it says "plugin update was not installed. See log..." and the log is lengthy and i cant understand it.

Anyone knows the fix?

Comment: @usman Try restarting Android Studio, see if that fixes it.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I had the same error message. There is also nothing in the logs. All you need to do is to restart Android Studio, Release 1.3.70 is very likely already installed, that's why you are getting the error.
After restarting, open the Tools menu, Kotlin, Configure Kotlin Plugin Updates and you will see that Release 1.3.70 is installed and that there are no updates available.